# SweetAlert2 Get the value from previous step

Tags: javascript, php, unix, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I need your help because I can not retrieve the value and do a test and then prefill the following field.
Basically if we select in the morning, the proposed time will be 7am otherwise we can still modify this time.

Thanks for your help

```
        progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
    })
        var test = 0;
        var steps = [
        {
            title: ' Choose user?',
            input: 'select',
            type: 'question',
            inputOptions: listeUser,
            confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
            showCancelButton: true,
        },
        {
            title: ' Morning, AM or Night ?',
            input: 'select',
            type: 'question',
            inputOptions: typequart,
            confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
            showCancelButton: true,
            **inputValidator: (value) => {if(value === "'Morning'"){test = 1;}**
        },
        {
            title: 'Hour',
            input: 'text',
            inputPlaceholder : 'HH-MM-SS',
            **inputValue: if(test=1){input here this value (07-00-00)}**
            type: 'info',
            confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
            showCancelButton: true,
        }];
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Give us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you. I can see you have an array of configuration objects, so I suppose you are calling sweetalert dynamically. How are you deciding which object to call each time? Is it a linear sequence? What the properties between `** **` mean?

Comment: Also, I don't think the "unix" tag belongs to your question.